# Double Decay: The Fish

Tags: riddle, word

I am a fish

---

Remove my first, and I might be a thief

Remove my second, and you will divide

Remove my third, and you will see much pain

Remove my fourth, and I am measured by metres

Remove my fifth, and nothing is left

---

Remove my fifth, and you see what I do

Remove my fourth, and you have space to think

Remove my third, and I will sound infantile

Remove my second, and things fall

Remove my first, and nothing is left

---

What am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This fish must be a

> **[gaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaper_(fish))** - a ray-finned fish found in the Indian Ocean.

Remove my first, and I might be a thief

> aper - someone who apes or copies something

Remove my second, and you will divide

> per - for each

Remove my third, and you will see much pain

> ER - Emergency Room

Remove my fourth, and I am measured by metres

> r - can stand for the radius of a circle

---

Remove my fifth, and you see what I do

> gape - stare in wonder

Remove my fourth, and you have space to think

> gap - a space

Remove my third, and I will sound infantile

> ga - babies go ga ga

Remove my second, and things fall

> g - symbol for the acceleration due to gravity